# R: Why can't use dimnames() to assign dim names

Tags: r

```
fg = read.table("fungus.txt", header=TRUE, row.names=1);fg
names(dimnames(fg)) = c("Temperature", "Area");names(dimnames(fg))#doesn't work
dimnames(fg) = list("Temperature"=row.names(fg), "Area"=colnames(fg));dimnames(fg) 
#doesn't work
```

You can look at the picture of data I used below:

[image: screen shot]

Using dimnames() to assign dim names to the data.frame doesn't work.

[image: Screen Shot]

The two R command both do not work. The dimnames of fg didn't change, and the names of dimnames of fg is still NULL.

Why does this happen? How to change the dimnames of this data.frame?

Comment: try `colnames(fg)` = c("Temperature", "Area")

Comment: How did you come up with your attempts? What is your logic there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found change the data frame to matrix works well.

```
fg = as.matrix(read.table("fungus.txt", header=TRUE, row.names=1))
dimnames(fg) = list("Temp"=row.names(fg), "Isolate"=1:8);fg
```

And got the output:

```
    Isolate
Temp    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
  55 0.66 0.67 0.43 0.41 0.69 0.63 0.46 0.52
  60 0.82 0.81 0.80 0.79 0.85 0.91 0.53 0.66
  65 0.91 1.09 0.81 0.86 0.95 0.93 0.64 1.10
  70 1.02 1.22 1.03 1.08 1.10 1.13 0.80 1.17
  75 1.06 1.17 0.89 1.02 1.06 1.29 0.94 1.01
  80 0.80 0.81 0.73 0.77 0.80 0.79 0.59 0.95
  85 0.26 0.40 0.36 0.53 0.67 0.53 0.57 0.18
```

Reply to the comments: if you do not know anything about the code, then do not ask me why I post such a question.